# How to create a 'template' view for each cardview in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a few cardviews in a recyclerview. When I click on one I want it to show a different layout.

This is the 'template' that each card should have when I click on it.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview_sam"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/reading_bg"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollviewSam"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="188dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/sam" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_light"
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_heavy"
            android:text="@string/about"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_heavy"
            android:text="@string/background"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_light"
            android:lineHeight="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="17sp"
            android:paddingRight="17sp"
            android:text="@string/about_sam"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_light"
            android:lineHeight="20sp"
            android:paddingLeft="17sp"
            android:paddingRight="17sp"
            android:text="@string/background_sam1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView19" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_light"
            android:lineHeight="20sp"
            android:paddingLeft="17sp"
            android:paddingRight="17sp"
            android:text="@string/background_sam2"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_heavy"
            android:text="@string/name_sam"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_heavy"
            android:text="@string/gender_male"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_light"
            android:text="@string/gender"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_light"
            android:text="@string/hair_color"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_heavy"
            android:text="@string/color_brown"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_light"
            android:text="@string/eye_color"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="176dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_light"
            android:text="@string/cast"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_width="101dp"
            android:layout_height="39dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="176dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_heavy"
            android:lineHeight="20dp"
            android:text="@string/cast_norman"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_heavy"
            android:text="@string/color_blue"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="224dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_heavy"
            android:text="@string/status_alive"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="224dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sackers_gothic_light"
            android:text="@string/status"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/like"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_favorite_border_24" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

This is my RecyclerViewAdapter.

```
  import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
    import com.example.myapplication.R;
    import com.example.myapplication.ScrollviewSam;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class CharacterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CharacterAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    
        List<String> name;
        List<Integer> images;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    
        public CharacterAdapter( Context context, List<String> name, List<Integer> images) {
            this.name = name;
            this.images = images;
            this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.character_grid_layout,parent,false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }
    
    
    
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.name.setText(name.get(position));
            holder.image.setImageResource(images.get(position));
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return name.size();
        }
    
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            TextView name;
            ImageView image;
    
            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    
                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (getAdapterPosition() == 0 ){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ScrollviewSam.class);
                            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                });
    
            }
        }
    
    
    }
```

As you can see I set a clickListener for the item. This is where it gets confusing for me since I created a new activity for the view but that will get super repetitive with creating the activity and the view over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Instead of checking the adapterPosition, and starting an Activity, you want to pass your data to the ViewHolder, and then to the Activity.
You can use onBindViewHo\lder() for the first, and `[Intents][1]` for the second part.

```
// In your adapter's onBindViewHolder
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindDataToYourViewHolder(name.get(position), images.get(position))
}
```

The above, will set the name and image in your ViewHolder. You need to adjust your ViewHolder slightly:

```
public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
}

public void bindDataToYourViewHolder(String yourName, int yourImage){

   name.setText(yourName);
   image.setImageResource(yourImage);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ScrollviewSam.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", yourName)
            // You can use yourImage here as well
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }                    
    });

}
```

This way, you can pass `name.getText()` to your `ScrollviewSam` Activity.
Inside ScrollviewSam.onCreate() you can grab the extra by doing:

```
// In ScrollviewSam Activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
}
```

Besides Strings, you can pass Booleans, Integer and more through Bundles. You can even pass around whole objects if they implement the Parcelable interface. But mostly, basic primitives should get you going.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about, that I will be just changing the strings, images in code but I can't see how does the onclick function know which card was clicked and how do I set the needed values for that?

Comment: Added onBindViewHolder example

Comment: Finally I get it! So in the Scrollview class I will just find the textViews and if the key matches, I will replace it with the String I want from the bundle! Tried it now and it works! Thanks for clarification man

Comment: Bingo! Enjoy creating great stuff :muscle:

Comment: Ok, but now heres another issue with the like button. It gets shared across the views. How do I bind in to the current view? Because when I click on it, the change will be visible in other view